# is ok to load the configuration data from the databse in Reactjs after successfull login?

Tags: reactjs, configuration

We have reactapp whhich currenly hold this configuraion in js file and
This configurations is having new values every two months.
because of this we need to deploy the application every month
To avoid the deployment, Is it ok to load these configuration form the database and assign to a constant after successful.

is configurations are loaded from database for react apps, I am only 4 moths experienced in React-js.
not sure of this.

We have some dropdown value currently configure as constants in js file ,we are planning to load this from database as well ?
anybody show some insight on this, if any reference to sample  code would be very helpful

thanks,

Comment: If you are connecting to a database directly from the direct front end with out any backend checks there may be security concerns as your configuration variables may be exposed.

Comment: thinking of fetching this configuration after the successful login? is there any better way

Comment: You could create a REST API to which you send the data from the react app. The database configurations should be done from the REST API server's end.